# Provide Color Theme to the `Java Process Console` in the Terminal of VSCode while running a Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, visual-studio-code, terminal

Is there a way to add colours/themes to the output generated in the `Java Process Console` which is a result of running a Spring Application from the VSCode `Spring-Boot-Dashboard`.

I am looking for a targetted solution for the `Java Process Console` that is outputted on the integrated `Terminal`. I am using `Git Bash` as my integrated terminal.

[image]

Comment: I am also irritated by vscode's monochromatic logging output. 
Have you found a solution already?

Answer (score 18):

add `spring.output.ansi.enabled=always` into your project `application.properties`
[enable vscode spring boot logs colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euJ4f.png)

Comment: I added the file to src and addressed it in the xml via     <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
I still don't see any colors...

Comment: This solution works for my initializer spring boot project

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

> spring.output.ansi.enabled=always